# how to call rails controller with particular id from angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am working in angularjs and rails and I want to call rails controller like this

```
.controller('SongController', ['$scope','FileUploader','$stateParams',function($scope, FileUploader,$stateParams) {

     $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({url: '/events/$stateParams.id/playlists'});

}]);
```

$stateParams.id should get replaced by event_id like 1 or 2 and url be like

```
/events/1/playlists
```

but it is not so

and it is giving me following error

```
No route matches [POST] "/events/$stateParams.id/playlists"
```

how to call the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to interpolate the actual id:

```
.controller('SongController', ['$scope','FileUploader','$stateParams',function($scope, FileUploader,$stateParams) {
   $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({url: '/events/' + $stateParams.id + '/playlists'});
}]);
```